# ELF перехват функции по адресу в библиотеке

Tags: hook, elf

Я для перехвата воспользовался вот этим (https://github.com/asLody/ElfHook). Все достаточно просто, но вот вопрос. Допустим я хочу перехватить ф-ию не по его названию, а по адресу, как допустим на картинке 0x0003E8CC.

[image: адрес ф-ии]

Я пытался получить адрес ф-ии, таким образом, base address + offset, но ничего не выходило, просто кидало сегфолт, а если точно так же перехватить, только использовав его имя, то все ок. Как можно перехватить ф-ию по его адресу?